# Birt Report: New Line character in Data Field.

Tags: java, eclipse, reporting-services, birt

Birt Report Data Field: 
type = String

Database Column:
type = varchar

When i try to fetch the data from database using birt report the data field fetch the data successfully. But the data contain some new line character like "Hello \n World" because i enter the data with some new lines.But the birt report data field print the "Hello World" in one line. it contain spaces but not new line charterer. How to print the data in birt report with new line.

Comment: I don't understand the problem OR how you got to where you are

Comment: the problem is that, in my data there are some new line character . when i open the data in text file, the text is properly formatted in new lines. but when i try to fetch the data in report. the new line character is ignore by birt dataset.

Comment: I don't have birt in front of me but the data component should have a type field with options like (HTML, plain, and maybe even auto).  Specify plain.  If that doesn't work, use the formula editor and replace the \n with <br> and set the component to HTML.

Comment: to raylee:
Are you sure, you are talking about data component? I saw choosing content type between Auto/Plain/Html only in text component. Or it's just old vers. of birt

Comment: thanks to all for reply, now used Dynamic Text component for formatting text. now we use `<br />` tag for new line.